# How to force Express.js to yield parameters with special characters as they are?

Tags: javascript, api, express, http, parameters

I am trying to complete a simple project in the freeCodeCamp "API and Microservices" curriculum.

The project is rather simple, it requires working with Express.js, some routes are provided and others must be dynamically generated. In this case, either a string or number that can be parsed as `new Date()` object. e.g.:

- 1451001600000, this is a valid UNIX time in milliseconds;
- 2016-12-25, is valid;
- 05%20October%202011 is valid as well.

This last one got me stuck and makes the response fail every time.
As a matter of fact, it gets accepted as valid in the Date() object. However, the resulting date is wrong because Express.js apparently parses or passes parameters rid of special characters.

Therefore, `05%20October%202011` gets logged out as `05 October 2011`.

I have looked in the Express.js documentation and elsewhere on MDN, etc.
Apparently, I have found several ways to do this with the `query` object, but not with the `params` object.

I have also tried to provide middlewares that could mitigate the problem, but the issue arises from the Express API itself, and providing URL parsing middlewares would not be useful because not all requests are sent with special characters.

Does anyone know how to prevent Express.js to get rid of special characters and pass the URL parameters as they are?

Remember that the routes are casually checked by FFC server, hence it is not possible to act on the input itself.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Whatever is sent to the server in the url should be urlencoded. If you want your param to be '05 October 2011', then you send '05%20October%202011’. If you want the param to be  '05%20October%202011’, then you must send the percents url-encoded, i.e. you send  '05%2520October%25202011’.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said at the bottom of my question, the FCC server makes random requests, therefore I have no control over the inputs. Anyway, it seems to be a problem of how the Date() object parse the 05%20October%202011. For some reason, the Date() object sees it as 05 October 2020, whereas the URL is clearly 05 October 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the task :)

Anything you type into a URL in a modern browser will be passed through `encodeURIComponent`. For example, if you go to `https://httpbin.org/get?data=one two three`, the browser will issue a request like `GET /get?data=one%20two%20three HTTP/2` (note that browsers may auto-convert `%20` to space for you when you inspect the request headers, in Firefox you can use the Raw switch on Headers tab).
[image: Raw switch]

The reason this is done is so that you can send text like `this/is/not/a/route` or `this&is=not&a=param` as parameters without them being parsed as paths or query parameters.

Conventiently, express will auto-decode this for you, so that you see that `req.params.data = 'one two three'`. There is no reason to fight this behaviour. Now, if you REALLY wanted to get your percents back, you could encode the parameter back using

```js
const encoded = encodeURIComponent(req.params.data);
console.log(encoded); // 'one%20two%20three'
```

For your example, what's probably intended is that express automatically decodes `05%20October%202011` into `05 October 2011`, which you can then use like `new Date(myAutomaticallyDecodedParam)`.

If you instead send `05%2520October%25202011` to the server, it will get decoded into `05%20October%202011`. It looks like Node will get the first number as the **day**, the first word as the **month**, and the first four digits after the month as the **year**, which for `October%202011` leads to the year 2020.

If something is still unclear, please add more context or ask away :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. Firstly, since it's a test it is quite hard to debug because what you get is either failed or passed. Therefore, trying to understand what was the problem (the date or the parsing) was a challenge. Secondly, the issue does not come from the URL parsing but from the way the Date object considers 05%20October%202011 a valid date. I am not saying it's wrong parsing or it's a bug, but it's just different from the URL standard decoding and this might generate some confusion. Anyway, I have learned something new, I guess. Thank you very much for your answers.